# Javascript variable semantics compared to Python

Tags: javascript, python

Unless I'm mistaken (always possible), all Python variables are exactly the same: references to a data object stored elsewhere. No Python variable holds a data value, only an always-dereferenced pointer to a value stored elsewhere. This means there is no problem saying, x=3; x="foo", because x just holds a pointer (and all pointers have the same size), which starts off pointing at the three and then the pointer (not the 3) is overwritten with another pointer that points at the string "foo". All function calls just copy the pointers in the arguments passed to them, regardless of what they point at. All type info, rules for immutability, etc., are stored in the data objects being pointed at, not in the variables.

I'm confused about Javascript variables, though. I keep reading that there are two types of JS vars, fundamental and Object. Fundamental data types (number, string, etc.) are stored in the variable itself while Objects have references stored in the variable, like Python. Java (not JS) is this way, but Java variables have a declared type, so you can't say, 'int x = 3; x = "foo" ' because 'int x' creates a piece of memory customized to ONLY hold an int.

But JS lets you say, 'var x=3; x="foo" ' without complaining. How can a piece of memory created to hold an int, not a pointer to int but the int itself, also hold an arbitrary string? Is this JS 'x' in fact a reference just pretending to hold the int, or does reassignment cause it to change location in memory if it needs to hold a different type, or what? And they say that strings are a fundamental data type in JS and that the value of a fundamental type is copied when passed to a function, so for a very long string, are there two copies of that string in memory if it is passed to a function instead of two copies of the pointer as is the case for "Object" types. Would recursion make a huge number of duplicates of a giant string?

The observable behavior ends up being like Python, as far as I can tell so far, and the books don't make a clear distinction between what is really going on and the effective consequences (reassigning a var in a function doesn't change it in the caller, etc.) Can anyone clarify the real, underlying semantics of Javascript variables?

Comment: Javascript variables are references, just like Python, PHP, and Lisp. Javascript has objects, but they're just a type of container (similar to Python dictionaries and PHP associative arrays), not a type of variable.

Comment: Are ALL Javascript variables references, like Python, with all semantic differences being in the datatypes they point to? Javascript books claim that when a variable "holding" a JS "object" is passed to a function, the reference (pointer) is copied, but when a variable "holding" a fundamental datatype is passed as an argument, the "value" is copied. Is that incorrect in the sense that there is no difference: all vars are references and all argument passing is pointer copying but, like Python, assignment through the pointer within the function behaves differently depending on what it points at?

Comment: JS's fundamental types are immutable, so there's no way to tell the difference between copying and references. Only objects and arrays can be modified, and they're passed as references.

Comment: FYI: The description of Python semantics here is accurate and a useful mental model, but be aware that it assumes implementation details. In some cases, some Python implementation may (PyPy does) deviate significantly from what you describe while still providing the exact same behavior.

Comment: Since string is a fundamental datatype, if I have a heavyweight web page in a single string and pass that string to a recursive algorithm, the difference between copying the string and copying the pointer could be huge. Are all Javascript variables required to be references, or is a variable "holding" a string allowed to hold either the value or a reference to the value as an unspecified implementation detail?

Comment: The string itself won't be checked for length when passed to some function. With that in mind, unless you are creating template literals with the HTML tags, try avoiding this in javascript and rather create DOM nodes/elements and use those instead of a massive string. Probably too late to the party but if it wasn't clear until now for anyone else, this should help.